# How to install Brave browser on Elementary OS?

Tags: software-installation

I just installed Elementary OS.

I'm switching from Windows 10, I don't know anything about Linux, I'm not a technical person.

I want to install Brave browser, I checked Brave guidelines, but I don't know what any of it means.

https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux

Can someone please help me install Brave? Thank you!

Comment: have you already tried http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/11/brave-browser-1-0-released-how-to-install-in-ubuntu-18-04/ ?

Comment: Hey, @VladPop!

I followed the instructions in the link you provided, but eventually I got this message:


'E: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/hera/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 151.101.114.217 443]
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com hera InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details'

How can I finish installing Brave?

Comment: Open /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list as sudo and replace `hera` with `stable` so that is says `deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main`. Save the change and try installing again `sudo apt update && sudo apt install brave-browser`

Comment: To open a file as sudo, right-click on `Files` -> `New Window as Administrator`

Comment: @VladPop, I'm sorry I'm not following since I don't know anything about using Linux, can you explain in more detail?

You said "Open /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list", am I supposed to open it using terminal? If so, how?

Also you say "To open file as sudo, right-click on Files -> New Window as Administrator", where do I find a Files menu?

Comment: @VladPop, it worked, thank you! :)

Comment: Good job! Some things really are different when compared to Windows, but others are strikingly similar: in Windows, you would have to 'Run as Administrator' some apps, and in linux you have to use sudo in front of some of the commands. `New Window as Administrator` just opens the `Files` app (like Windows' Explorer) as sudo (after you input your password).

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the Ubuntu installation. Open the terminal and follow the steps.

```
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl

$ curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -

$ echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install brave-browser
```

Comment: I tried that previously and it didn't work, but now it worked after editing brave.list file. Thank you for your answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can also install it via Snap:

```
sudo snap install brave
```